# GWT Atmosphere - browser hangs on refresh (2.1.0-RC2)

Tags: gwt, atmosphere

I am using Atmosphere for GWT 2.1.0-RC2 and am experiencing the browser (Both Firefox 24+ and Chrome 30) hang when I refresh. This happens both in production and GWT dev mode.

Looking at the browsers console I see this connection hanging:

```
http://localhost:8080/atmosphere/rpc?site-id=MERGEFOLDER:adminA7559865-3550-4A7D-A60E-7208CFE28FFE&site-type=com.j.apps.merge.server.MergeFolderCollabSite&X-Atmosphere-Transport=close&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=bcdbf745-cf61-4ca7-92ed-0df8828931ea&_=1395341362393
```

And directly after it the error:

```
The connection to ws://localhost:8080/atmosphere/rpc?site-id=MERGEFOLDER:adminA7559865-3550-4A7D-A60E-7208CFE28FFE&site-type=com.j.apps.merge.server.MergeFolderCollabSite&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.0.5-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=text/x-gwt-rpc;%20charset=UTF-8&X-atmo-protocol=true was interrupted while the page was loading.
http://localhost:8080/atmosphere-min.js
Line 259
```

I have been poking around to try and find out why this might be happening but haven't found any leads.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using GWT 2.1 Release candidate when GWT 2.6.0 is released?

Comment: That is the Atmosphere version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with atmosphere 2.1.2, GWT and JBoss and finally noticed there was a warning when the web application started:
`"Found multiple containers, please specify which one to use: org.atmosphere.container.JettyCometSupport, org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport, org.atmosphere.container.NettyCometSupport,  until you do, Atmosphere will use:class org.atmosphere.container.JettyCometSupport".`
I explicitly set the async support class in web.xml:
`<init-param>
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.asyncSupport</param-name>
    <param-value>org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport</param-value>
</init-param>`
and refresh is working as expected now.